# Remove authentication required popup on Azure Active directory with .net core

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0, adfs, nightwatch.js

I am using .net core 2.0 application with ADFS for authentication. When I access web app from linux, I get additional authentication required po up on office network. Pop up not asked in outside office network or office device.

[image]

i need to remove the additional popup or enter user credentials with Nightwatch automation test.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Nightwatch nor underlying Selenium doesn't support interaction with this popup unfortunately, but what you can do is to pass username and password with URL:

```
client
  .url('https://username:password@example.com')
```

**Update:**

The solution above won't work if the URL you open the first doesn't require auth (and looks like this is your case).

What you can do, is to pre-authenticate browser before running actual test by visiting any URL which requires auth, so auth header will be added for every next request in this browser session. You might as well use `before` hook of your test suite:

```
module.exports = {
  before: function(client, done) {
    client.url('https://username:password@someurl.com/auth').perform(function() {
      done();
    });
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: Are you accessing this URL by clicking some element on the page? Or this is the first URL you open by your script?

Comment: I open and application with Azure ad authentication. It redirects to azure ad where it need username and password. I do not know how to authorize it.

Comment: @BlackPOP I've updated my answer with some addition information which might help you

Comment: Pre authenticate? if i can (pre)authenticate, i can integrate with test itself. right?

Comment: Sure, just put that `client.url()` call at the top of test run

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a custom browser profile which is already logged in.

A useful discussion on how to pass a custom firefox profile:
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1543